# cannot read property "connect" of undefined - nestjs/mongoose

Tags: mongoose, graphql, nestjs

I'm running a NestJs application with GraphQL and Mongoose.

**database/database.providers.ts**
*I have checked the mongoDB connection string and it's correct.*

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING} from './constants/constants';

export const databaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
        useFactory: async (): Promise<typeof mongoose> =>
        {
            console.log(mongoose)
            const connection = await mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING)
            console.log(connection)
            return connection
        }
    },
];
```

The 2 console.log's return undefined in the case above.

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ApartmentModule,
    UsersModule,
    FavoriteModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: "schema.gql",
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    DatabaseModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, ...databaseProviders, ...userProviders],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**database.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    providers: [...databaseProviders],
    exports: [...databaseProviders],
    imports: [ConfigModule]
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

When I run the NestJs application, I get the following error:

```
[Nest] 9276  - 26/10/2021, 08:36:45     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 9276  - 26/10/2021, 08:36:45   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'connect' of 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

This undefined refers to the mongoose object imported from mongoose with which I run *mongoose.connect*

Comment: Try to use `MongooseModule.forRootAsync()` instead of `MongooseModule.forRoot()`

Comment: MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        uri: MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING,
      }),
    }),

I replaced forRoot with the above, still get the same error.